# android: wrong drawable resource file when changing layout direction

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, right-to-left

I created different drawable resource folders for rtl and ltr layout directions.(drawable-ldrtl & drawable-ldltr)

I use the following code to change layout directionL `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(getWindow().getDecorView(), View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)`

everything works fine about mirroring layouts, but the problem is that the drawable resource file doesn't change.

did I forget anything?

Comment: you are trying to change layout by swiching between languages?

Comment: Did you provide the proper drawable resource file in the proper drawable folder?

Comment: @Rotwang yes...

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy yes...

Comment: @mrezash drawables are with the same names?

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy yes sir.